# Can I access DataTemplate into codebehind

Tags: wpf

I am using WPF and I have `DataTemplate` that is i want to access into the codebehind
how I can use this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Age}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

public Window1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DataTemplate dataTemplate = FindResource("PersonDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
}
```

Comment: but how to find control that is inside DataTemplate i.e TextBlock and change the value at runtime from codebehind? Please help...!

Comment: Thanks! Was looking for this :D